# Accesstoken error when trying to conncet to SkypeOnlineConnector module in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

I'm trying to connect to sfb module in PowerShell but getting the following error

```
PS C:\windows\system32> import-module skypeonlineconnector
$sfbSession = New-CsOnlineSession
Import-PSSession $sfbSession
Please enter the user principal name (ex. User@Domain.Com): Myadminaccount
```

**Result:**

```
Get-CsAccessToken : One or more errors occurred.
At C:\Program Files\Common Files\Skype for Business Online\Modules\skypeonlineconnector\SkypeOnlineConnectorStartup.psm1:128 char:22
+ ... cessToken = Get-CsAccessToken -UserName $UserName -TargetUri $targetU ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-CsAccessToken], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.AggregateException,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.OnlineConnector.GetAccessToken
```

Then my colleague tried on the same machine but it works fine with him.
I searched for an answer on the internet but no luck, all the answers I found them refers to either update the skype module or disabling the MFA. But we both (me and my colleague) have the same settings.

Can anyone knows where is the problem, does it has anything to do with my admin account are missing some permissions?

Below is my sfb module version:
PS `C:\windows\system32> Get-Module -name SkypeOnlineConnector`

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                              
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                              
Script     7.0.0.0    skypeonlineconnector                {New-CsOnlineSession, Set-WinRMNetworkDelayMS}
```

Regards,

Comment: It is the problem with the specific user. Also, you have told that it is working fine with your colleague's username on the same machine itself.

Comment: Yes I know that there is something missing in my admin account, We double-checked our permissions on online exchange server and they have the same permissions. I just want more tips about where to look more.